# If $f(a) = 0$ but $f'(a)\ne 0$, find formula for residue for $\frac{1}{f(z)^2}$ at $z=a$ involving values of derivatives of $f$ at $a$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose $f(z)$ is an analytic function in a neighborhood of a point $a$. If $f(a) = 0$ but $f'(a)\ne 0$, find formula for residue for 
>   $\frac{1}{f(z)^2}$ at $z=a$ involving values of derivatives of $f$ at $a$.

Since $f$ has a simple zero at $a$, we can write $f(z) = (z-a)F(z)$, where $F(a)\ne 0$ and $F(z)$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $a$. Then

$$
\frac{1}{f(z)^2} = \frac{1}{(z-a)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{F(z)^2},
$$
where $\frac{1}{F(z)^2}$ is analytic at $a$. Thus

$$
\frac{1}{F(z)^2} = A_0 + A_1(z-a) + A_2(z-a)^2+\cdots
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{f(z)^2} = \frac{A_0}{(z-a)^2} + \frac{A_1}{(z-a)}+\cdots
$$
So $\text{Res}_a\,\frac{1}{f(z)^2} = A_1.$
But then 
$$
A_1 = \frac{d}{dz}\,\left.\frac{1}{F(z)^2}\right|_{z=a} = -\frac{2}{F(a)^3} = -\frac{2}{f'(a)^3}.
$$

Does this look right?

Comment: looks to me like you need to apply the chain rule and multiply the result by $F'(a)$.

Comment: Yes! Not sure how I missed that.